# Filter rows based on multiple advanced criterias in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, filtering, data-manipulation

Currently I'm performing some calculations on a database that contains information on how loans are paid by borrowers.

And my goal is to create a new dataframe that will include loans that fall under the following criteria:

- a borrower (ID) has at least 2 loans;
- each subsequent loan is less than previous one and issued 15 days after the repayment of the previous loan;
- last loans (outstanding loans with no ClosingDate) are bigger than previous loan.

Here is my dataframe:

```
Name    ID     ContractDate LoanSum ClosingDate
A       ID1    2022-10-10   10      2022-10-15 
A       ID1    2022-10-16   8       2022-10-25
A       ID1    2022-10-27   25      
B       ID2    2022-12-12   10      2022-10-15
B       ID2    2022-12-16   22      2022-11-18
B       ID2    2022-12-20   9       2022-11-25
B       ID2    2023-11-29   13      
C       ID3    2022-11-11   30      2022-11-18
```

My expected result is:

```
Name    ID     ContractDate LoanSum ClosingDate
A       ID1    2022-10-10   10      2022-10-15 
A       ID1    2022-10-16   8       2022-10-25
A       ID1    2022-10-27   25      
B       ID2    2022-12-12   10      2022-10-15
B       ID2    2022-12-16   22      2022-11-18
B       ID2    2022-12-20   9       2022-11-25
B       ID2    2023-11-29   13
```

What I have already done:
(the code below helps to catch loans but it does not include outstanding loans with no ClosingDate that are bigger than previous loans)

```
cols = df.columns
w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('ContractDate')

newdf = df.withColumn('PreviousContractDate', f.lag('ContractDate').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('PreviousLoanSum', f.lag('LoanSum').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('Target', f.expr('datediff(ContractDate, PreviousContractDate) >= 1 and datediff(ContractDate, PreviousContractDate) < 16 and LoanSum - PreviousLoanSum < 0')) \
  .withColumn('Target', f.col('Target') | f.lead('Target').over(w)) \
  .filter('Target == True')
```

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks a lot for ideas / solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the expected output, try the following logic

```py
newdf = (df.withColumn('PreviousContractDate', f.lag('ContractDate').over(w)) 
  .withColumn('PreviousLoanSum', f.lag('LoanSum').over(w)) 
  .withColumn('Target', f.expr('(datediff(ContractDate, PreviousContractDate) >= 1 and datediff(ContractDate, PreviousContractDate) < 16) or ((LoanSum > PreviousLoanSum)  and (ClosingDate is null))' )) 
  .withColumn('Target', f.col('Target') | f.lead('Target').over(w)) 
  .filter('Target == True'))
```

Below is the full code snippet

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LoanFiltering").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-10-10", 10, "2022-10-15"),
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-10-16", 8, "2022-10-25"),
    ("A", "ID1", "2022-10-27", 25, None),
    ("B", "ID2", "2022-12-12", 10, "2022-10-15"),
    ("B", "ID2", "2022-12-16", 22, "2022-11-18"),
    ("B", "ID2", "2022-12-20", 9, "2022-11-25"),
    ("B", "ID2", "2023-11-29", 13, None),
    ("C", "ID3", "2022-11-11", 30, "2022-11-18")
]

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ContractDate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("LoanSum", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("ClosingDate", StringType(), True)
])

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Convert date columns to DateType
df = df.withColumn("ContractDate", f.to_date("ContractDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df = df.withColumn("ClosingDate", f.to_date("ClosingDate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

# Create a window specification to order rows by ContractDate within each ID partition
w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("ContractDate")

newdf = (df.withColumn('PreviousContractDate', f.lag('ContractDate').over(w)) 
  .withColumn('PreviousLoanSum', f.lag('LoanSum').over(w)) 
  .withColumn('Target', f.expr('(datediff(ContractDate, PreviousContractDate) >= 1 and datediff(ContractDate, PreviousContractDate) < 16) or ((LoanSum > PreviousLoanSum)  and (ClosingDate is null))' )) 
  .withColumn('Target', f.col('Target') | f.lead('Target').over(w))
  .filter('Target == True'))

newdf.show()
```